# How to create a simple dashboard angular widget?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-module

I installed **[malhar-angular-dashboard](https://github.com/DataTorrent/malhar-angular-dashboard)** module for my angular application and I want to create a simple widget that displays some dummy text.

**HTML view**

```
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div dashboard="timeDashboardsOptions" class="dashboard-container"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$scope.timeDashboardsOptions = {
    widgetDefinitions: [  // list required
      {
        name: 'timeWidget', // option required
        template: '<div>hello {{widget.title}}</div>',
        settingsModalOptions: {
          templateUrl: 'views/dashboards/widget-area/time.html'
        }
        ,
        onSettingsClose: function(resultFromModal, widgetModel, dashboardScope) {
          // do something to update widgetModel, like the default implementation:
          jQuery.extend(true, widget, result);
        },
        onSettingsDismiss: function(reasonForDismissal, dashboardScope) {
          // probably do nothing here, since the user pressed cancel
        }
      }
    ],
    defaultWidgets: [ // list required
      {name:'timeWidget'}
    ]
  };
```

**Widget template**

```
<div>
  <h3>Time widget</h3>
</div>
```

When I run it, I get this kind of result:

```css
ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline;
}
.middle {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #f0ad4e;
  border-color: #eea236;
}
.last {
  background-color: #5bc0de;
  border-color: #46b8da;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class='first'>timeWidget - missing ???</li>
  <li>
    <button class='middle'>Default Widgets</button>
  </li>
  <li class='last'>
    <button class='last'>Clear</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

and the error

> TypeError: _.merge is not a function
>       at Object.WidgetModel (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/malhar-angular-dashboard/dist/malhar-angular-dashboard.js:848:42)

Comment: Looks like that module depends on the underscore library.

Comment: Bower installed underscore module also, I checked and it`s there, so yes, I have underscore.js (<script src="bower_components/underscore/underscore.js"></script>)

Comment: Is it included on your page before the angular dashboard?

Comment: Yes, I tried this already :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove **underscore.js** and let **loadash.js** handle it.